# C - optimal way to check if not equal

Tags: c, optimization, x86

What is the optimal code for the following block:

```
if (a != b)
    a = b
```

Comment: The optimal way is simply `a = b;`

Comment: Or even no code at all? Depends what is coming after (and/or before, actually).

Comment: @WeatherVane: Might be worth mentioning that replacing the original code like this *could* in theory introduce a data race in a multithreaded program.

Comment: @WeatherVane If One is `volatile` it makes a great difference.

Comment: Or if some of these are macros..

Comment: Or if `a` is a hardware register.

Comment: @WeatherVane Then it would probably be `volatile` as Olaf said.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I meant in the case that a write triggers an action.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah, good point.

Comment: @WeatherVane but when using `a=b` wouldnt that  introduce a write always, even when `(a == b)` is true?

Comment: @balajimc55 So? Who cares? (in case the corner use-cases above are not applicable)

Comment: @balajimc55 that was the point of my previous comment.

Comment: But my first comment took the code at face value. A branch can be more expensive than a simple read-write. Your code does a read-read-branch or a read-read-write, mine does a read-write.

Comment: @WeatherVane hmm yeah, good point

Comment: There is a very hypothetical situation where a write is *much* more expensive than read and branch. Then it might make sense to avoid writes whenever it is possible.

Comment: As they say, write for clarity first, optimize second. Can't get much clearer than `a=b;`!

Comment: Would it be excessively mean to downvote this for no MCVE?  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
a = b;
```

because this way only one assignment will be run every time instead of the possibility of a condition check and an assignment.

Comment: In asm (intel syntax), just `mov b,a`